# Using Xaml WorkFlow In Another Xaml workflow in Rehosted Designer

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, workflow, rehosting

I'm writing  a workflow WPF Designer  Re hosting Application and I want to  use An Xaml Inside Another One(Like Sub Workflow) I make workflow file with sub workflow  In Vs 2013 workflow Designer but in my Re hosting Application It's not working Actually The Application Couldn't Recognize it.

I also loaded my Xaml Sub workflow file in an activity in this way:

```
Activity workflow1 = ActivityXamlServices.Load(ActivityXamlServices.CreateReader(new    XamlXmlReader(@"C:\insideworkflow.xaml", new XamlXmlReaderSettings { LocalAssembly = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly() })));
```

and I want to know how should I load it to designer which the designer could recognize it also I want to use sub workflow in toolbox and reuse it how can I make it reusable.

Comment: It's not possible. Or maybe you wont do it if i would tell you what would be required. Just a few pointers: You would need to invoke MsBuild to create the code behind files for your Sub Workflows. You must then Build the assemblies from that. The assemblies need to be loaded to use the activities. You need to host the designer in ist own appdomain so you can unload the appdomain if you want to compensate for changes to the sub Workflows. I have done this, and it's not worth it. You end up with your own implementation of Visual Studio...

Comment: Thank You Florian Dohrendorf for your help Could you Please Send me The code of what you mentioned. actually i want to give the Application to my clients so They can have their own Flow.

Comment: I can only roughly Point you in the right direction. I can't share that code, because it's work product. Also to repeat myself, you really shouldn't do that. My implementation hardly works and still has a lot of quirks, and i already invested more than a year. Now that Project is on ice, because it will not workout as planned, and we started building our own workflow engine to Support that scenario.

Comment: Also have a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4263715/working-with-sub-workflow-in-rehosted-designer?rq=1 maybe that might be enough for your needs.

Comment: Thank You Florian for your Help It helps me a lot . i think i have to Change Some Parts ;)